# Displaying, overlaying and interpreting live video feed in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, video, opencv, video-capture

I am starting a new project to show live video in a Windows form from an attached web cam and overlay that video with windows controls (buttons etc). Additionally I would like to do some image correction to remove distortion on the fly and do some edge detection.

I'm confused as to which library might be best suited for this.

1. OpenCVSharp - Can handle the correction / detection, not sure if overlay / live feed is possible.
2. DirectShow/DirectShow.Net - Do I need to code filters up for the
   overlay, how to handle edge detection?
3. AForge.net - It's been recommended but I'm not sure it is as capable

Does anyone have experience of these or other libs that might be suitable for access from .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to work with the vision part then AForge.net is your best bet. I have used it in the past and it was pretty good for video/feed stuff. Don't expect to do something with your audio later on though since AForge.NET only supports Vision related stuff. Personally I wouldn't use DirectShow since that is pretty old and sometimes requires you to do some complex interop tricks to get what you want. If you want to go the DirectShow way at least use DirectShow.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish that with [OpenCVSharp](http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/) and the instructions from [transparent image overlay](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/).